# Forbidden access to Wildfly Greeter quickstart application in Wildfly 10 server

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am trying to run wildfly-greeter project on the wildfyl-10 server.

I did everything as it is described on the link https://github.com/sgilda/wildfly-quickstart/tree/master/greeter-spring and everything worked as described.I also deployed the war file to the server, but when I try to access the link `http://localhost:8080/wildfly-greeter` in my browser (Firefox) I get an error "Forbidden".

[image]

I am also attaching console log of my wildfly server installation:

```
    14:52:32,529 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JSF1018: [/wildfly-greeter] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.disableUnicodeEscaping' set to 'auto'
    14:52:32,529 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JSF1018: [/wildfly-greeter] Configuration option 'javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD' set to '2'
    14:52:32,529 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JSF1018: [/wildfly-greeter] Configuration option 'javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS' set to 'auto'
    14:52:32,529 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JSF1018: [/wildfly-greeter] Configuration option 'javax.faces.CLIENT_WINDOW_MODE' set to 'none'
    14:52:32,529 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JSF1018: [/wildfly-greeter] Configuration option 'javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY' set to '/resources'
    14:52:32,529 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JSF1018: [/wildfly-greeter] Configuration option 'javax.faces.WEBAPP_CONTRACTS_DIRECTORY' set to '/contracts'
    14:52:32,530 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/jsf/ProjectStage -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-greeter.wildfly-greeter.env.jsf.ProjectStage
    14:52:32,534 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12-jbossorg-2 20150729-1131 for context '/wildfly-greeter'
    14:52:32,636 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.timing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)  [TIMING] - [72ms] : Parse jar:file:/I:/JavaTools/project_ee/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sun/jsf-impl/main/jsf-impl-2.2.12-jbossorg-2.jar!/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml
    14:52:32,638 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.timing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)  [TIMING] - [1ms] : Parse jar:file:/I:/JavaTools/project_ee/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/jsf-injection/main/wildfly-jsf-injection-10.0.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
    14:52:32,639 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.timing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)  [TIMING] - [1ms] : Parse file:/I:/JavaTools/project_ee/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp59b1b492c689169e/content-a70656c2e0288dcf/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
    14:52:32,643 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Starting sort pass number 1...
    14:52:32,644 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Comparing , 
    14:52:32,644 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.timing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)  [TIMING] - [1ms] : "faces-config" document sorting complete in 1.
    14:52:32,648 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JSF1032: Resource injection ENABLED using InjectionProvider 'org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JSFInjectionProvider'.
    14:52:32,651 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JandexAnnotationProvider.<init>(javax.servlet.ServletContext, com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JandexAnnotationProvider.<init>(javax.servlet.ServletContext, com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider)
       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
       at com.sun.faces.spi.ServiceFactoryUtils.getProviderFromEntry(ServiceFactory.java:83)
       at com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProviderFactory.createAnnotationProvider(AnnotationProviderFactory.java:70)
       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.<init>(ConfigManager.java:931)
       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:385)
       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

    14:52:32,652 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.timing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)  [TIMING] - [0ms] : Configuration annotation scan complete.
    . 
    .
    .
    . 
    14:52:33,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
    14:52:33,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
    14:52:33,091 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started in 5190ms - Started 406 of 674 services (383 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
    14:54:39,988 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb.client.txn] (Periodic Recovery) Send recover request for transaction origin node identifier 1 to EJB receiver with node name *******
    14:54:49,990 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb.client.txn] (Periodic Recovery) Send recover request for transaction origin node identifier 1 to EJB receiver with node name *******
    14:56:22,027 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Reflection] (default task-2) WELD-000620: interface javax.enterprise.inject.Intercepted is not declared @Target(METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE). Weld will use this annotation, however this may make the application unportable.
    14:56:22,028 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Reflection] (default task-2) WELD-000620: interface javax.enterprise.inject.Decorated is not declared @Target(METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE). Weld will use this annotation, however this may make the application unportable.
```

The last two entries in the log file happened when I tried to access the wildfly-greeter application from browser.

Comment: @Bob: Thanks for editing my post. In your opinion, should I take care of anything special regarding writing posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is at the top of the GitHub repo `This branch is 227 commits behind wildfly:10.x."`. Might I suggest using a more current version of the example at:

[jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/spring-greeter](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/7.0.x-develop/spring-greeter).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yesss, it worked :). So, this means that it is a better to look for the newest quickstart projects on the link you provided?

Comment: I looked a little bit into the problem and found out that there is missing index.html in the src/main/webapp (greeter project from old repository). Should I report this to someone, that this is corrected?

Comment: Well, your original project was forked from the [Wildfly Quickstarts](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart), and they don't seem to have a spring-greeter anymore, so I don't think there is anyone to report it to. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I also saw in the header that the problematic project is forked from wildfly/quickstart. I will be more carefull in the future.